# Calculating maritime distances around barriers

Tags: r, geospatial, distance, r-raster

I am currently working on calculating distances of fishing vessels between catch locations (lat - long), and have tried using the `gdistance` package and adapting the code from this thread: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/03/computing-maritime-routes-in-r/

However, even running the example code and my code, I get the following error when using the transition() function:

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function
> 'extent': ‘srs’ is not a slot in class “BasicRaster”

Example code:

```r
library(gdistance)
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)
library(data.table)

#create a raster from shape files
shp <- wrld_simpl
r <- raster()
r <- rasterize(shp, r, progress='text')

#make all sea = -999
r[is.na(r)] <- -999
#this turns all landmass to missing
r[r>-999] <- NA
#assign unit cost to all grid cells in water
r[r==-999] <- 1

tr <- transition(r, mean, directions = 8)

# THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR MESSAGE.

tr <- geoCorrection(tr, "c")

AtoB <- shortestPath(tr, as.numeric(start[1:2]), as.numeric(end[1:2]), 
                     output = "SpatialLines")
```

I'm not sure if it is my computer, and maybe a different package is masking it. But I have been trying to debug it for a couple of days, but no dice.

Comment: When I run your code, the line `tr <- geoCorrection(tr, "c")` gives a different error: `as(<dsCMatrix>, "dgTMatrix") is deprecated since Matrix 1.5-0; do as(as(., "generalMatrix"), "TsparseMatrix") instead`. More generally, the maptools package is in the process of being retired and is no longer guaranteed to work. You may want to update your code to not rely on maptools or the deprecated features in Matrix, to see if that helps.

Comment: @MattAshby That's actually a warning, not an error. It shouldn't affect results. Regardless, it's addressed in an upcoming version of gdistance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/AgrDataSci/gdistance/issues/14) for this.

Basically, my suspicion is that the issue originated in terra, and that at some point it was fixed (I don't know this for sure). So try updating both the terra and raster packages.

Answer (score 0):

This likely happens because your version of gdistance was built with an older version of "raster". It should go away of you install "gdistance" again (preferably from source).